# How to save prediction values for the whole data in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, machine-learning-model, vgg16

I am using pre-trained VGG16 model to classify images located in the folder. Currently, I am able to classify only one single image.

1. How can I modify the code to classify all the images in the folder
2. How can I save the prediction values for each image ?

Below is my code :

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import decode_predictions
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = 'cat.jpg'
# load an image in PIL format
original = load_img(filename, target_size=(224, 224))
print('PIL image size',original.size)
plt.imshow(original)
plt.show()

# convert the PIL image to a numpy array
# IN PIL - image is in (width, height, channel)
# In Numpy - image is in (height, width, channel)
numpy_image = img_to_array(original)
plt.imshow(np.uint8(numpy_image))
plt.show()
print('numpy array size',numpy_image.shape)

# Convert the image / images into batch format
# expand_dims will add an extra dimension to the data at a particular axis
# We want the input matrix to the network to be of the form (batchsize, height, width, channels)
# Thus we add the extra dimension to the axis 0.
image_batch = np.expand_dims(numpy_image, axis=0)
print('image batch size', image_batch.shape)
plt.imshow(np.uint8(image_batch[0]))



# prepare the image for the VGG model
processed_image = vgg16.preprocess_input(image_batch.copy())

# get the predicted probabilities for each class
predictions = vgg_model.predict(processed_image)
print (predictions)

# convert the probabilities to class labels
# We will get top 5 predictions which is the default
#label = decode_predictions(predictions)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First, you could always just wrap you code with a loop.

```
files = [file1, file2, ...]
predictions = []
for file in files:
    original = load_img(file, target_size=(224, 224))
    numpy_image = img_to_array(original)
    image_batch = np.expand_dims(numpy_image, axis=0)
    processed_image = vgg16.preprocess_input(image_batch)  # you dont need to copy :)      predictions_cur = vgg_model.predict(processed_image)
    print(predictions_cur)
    predictions.append(predictions_cur)
    #label = decode_predictions(predictions_cur)
```

Secondly, you could improve the efficiency of this code by using the tf.data api.
For example:

```
from tensorflow.data import Dataset

batch_size = 32
num_threads = 4
target_size=(224, 224)

def preprocess_image(file):
    # file is not a tensor, so we have to use functions that work on tensors
    img_string = tf.read_file(file)
    img = tf.image.decode_png(img_string)
    img = tf.image.resize_images(target_size)
    img = vgg16.preprocess_input(img)  # this function can handle tensors as well.
    return img

files = [file1, file2, ...]
dataset = Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.constant(files))
dataset = dataset.map(preprocess_image, num_threads)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)  
predictions = vgg_model.predict(dataset, steps=len(files) // batch_size)
# You could decode the predictions from here :)
```

## Explanation

Let me elaborate on each step :)

`dataset.from_tensor_slices(files)` Will just build a dataset object, where the samples it will use are your files.

`dataset.map(preprocess_image, num_threads)`
This indicates to preprocess each sample before we use it.
This will also be made in *num_threads* parallel calls, which will haste the process in case we batch samples together for prediction.

`dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)`
This will batch samples together for prediction. This is useful to make predictions in parallel and haste the process.

`dataset.prefetch(1)`
This will prefatch the next batch while the previous one is being predicted upon. So this will also make the process faster because you save time this way.

and finally `predictions = vgg_model.predict(dataset, steps=len(files) // batch_size)`
This will predict over the all the files we've provided to the dataset above.
Do notice that we indicate that the number of steps is *len(files) // batch_size* so if *len(files)* isn't a multiply of *batch_size*, some images will not be predicted upon. If you want all the images to be predicted upon, you can use a batch_size that divides *len(files)*, or just use batch_size = 1.